# Coded UI Handcoding, getting a control from a div

Tags: c#, html, coded-ui-tests

I'm working on a page that has multiple htmldocument's with the same properties. i would like to extract it from a specific div that i can identify by an id, i had done it in a way before like

```
var div = new HtmlDiv();
div.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "collapseExecution";
HtmlControl test1 = new HtmlControl(div);
test1.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlIFrame.PropertyNames.PageUrl, WebInstance.GetURL() + "Activity/Create");
var k = test1.FindMatchingControls();

Mouse.Click(k[2]);
Keyboard.SendKeys("ABC");
```

however it seems to be unreliable as it doesn't always work on other computers. i feel like there should be a way to have a specified div as a parent to search in specifically. if so the way to do it would be very valuable information to me and would be extremely useful in the future

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't always work on other computers" ?  Do you get an error?

Comment: yes, it won't identify the same on other computer's i guess, it can't find the same amount of children in the div so for example, on my bosses computer it breaks because it says that index 2 is out of range for the k array

Comment: none the less, there should be a way to specify the div and only search for the control inside that div instead of looking through the entire uitestcontrol